# What does the Bonzai Bomb do?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

What is a Bonzai Bomb in Dungeons of Dredmor? It's one of the default alchemy crafting recipes, and I think it was added in the "Realm of the Diggle Gods" expansion, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I can't find any references for it, not even on the wiki. I would suggest use it and hope you don't explode? By the name alone, i'm thinking something in the line of a bomb that you throw that shouts Bonzaaaaaiii! and rushes toward an enemy (or yourself) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to inflict the [Skatha's Roots](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Skatha%27s_Roots#Granted_Abilities) effect on the monster it hits, and leaves a 1 space poison cloud which causes [Vile Poison](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Vile_Poison).